# LSTM - MAPE Loss Function gives Better Results when Data is De-Scaled before Loss Calculation

Tags: long-short-term-memory, objective-functions, weights, loss, scalability

I am building an `LSTM` for predicting a price chart. `MAPE` resulted in the best loss function compared to `MSE` and `MAE`. `MAPE` function looks like this

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum^N_{i=0}\frac{|P_i - A_i|}{A_i}$$

Where $P_i$ is the current predicted value and $A_i$ is the corresponding actual value. In neural network, it is always advised to scale the data between a small range close to zeros such as `[0, 1]`. In this case scaling range of `[0.001, 1]` is imperative to remove a possible division by zero.

Due to the `MAPE` denominator, the close the scaling range is to zero the larger the loss function becomes for a given $|P_i - A_i|$. If on the other hand, the data is de-scaled just before it is inserted in the `MAPE` function, the same $|P_i - A_i|$ would give a smaller `MAPE`

Consider a hypothetical example with a batch size of 1, $|P_i - A_i| = 2$ (this is scale indipendent) and $A_i = 200$. Therefore scaled $A_i = 0.04$. The `MAPE` error loss for the scaled version would be $\frac{2}{0.04} = 50$, and for the unscaled version $\frac{2}{200} = 0.01$

This will mean that the derivative w.r.t each weight of the scaled version will also be larger, therefore making the weights themselves even smaller. Is this correct?

I am concluding that scaling the data when using `MAPE` will effectively shrink the weights down more than necessary. Is that a good reason why I am seeing **significantly** better performance with de-scaled `MAPE` calculation?

**Note**: I am not keeping the same hyperparameters for scaled and de-scaled `MAPE` but a Bayesian optimization is performed with both runs, In the later a deeper network was preferred but in the scaled `MAPE` more regularisation was preferred.

Some expertise on this would be helpful.